# How to know when application download completes in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, download, app-store

I want to take time when user downloads an application from market or from any other app-store.

Is there any intent action to register for download complete thing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how to download file here as an example http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device and just return a boolean value when it finishes and use it as your isDownladed flag.

```
public boolean DownloadFromUrl(String imageURL, String fileName) 
{
try{
   URL url = new URL(imageURL);
.....
}
} catch (IOException e) {

                        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
return false;
                }
return true;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, above code will work perfectly if we know downloading URL path. But i don't know from which URL user will download the application. At this condition how can we take download finish time?

Comment: you just pass imageURL parameter to the  URL url = new URL(imageURL); within the method and use the DownloadFromUrl(...) anywhere

Comment: i was trying above code but could not get. i have added             URL url = new URL(imageURL);                                                     instead of  URL url = new URL("http://yoursite.com/&quot; + imageURL);  still not getting and also added permissions

Comment: well you have to pass the url to this method to download the file :)))

Comment: Thank you, if you get answer or any hint let me know please.

Comment: what is the exception? do you have any? paste the code how you used the method from example please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7096/discussion-between-vani-and-sergey-benner)